Is Peirce’s Law seen as a principle for relevance logics?
As far as I can tell, ‘relevance’ is a bit of a nebulous term depending on which logicians you ask, but that each of them has a rigorous view of what it means.
Consider the formula known as Peirce’s Law:
((P→Q)→P)→P.

This is a non-constructive theorem of Classical Logic. Unless I am misinterpreting something, it has at least some version of the variable-sharing principle.
I know that a formula having the variable-sharing principle is necessary for it to be a relevant implication, but I am fairly certain that it is not sufficient.
I also know that among relatively weak other axioms, that Peirce’s law proves non-relevant theorems such as
P→(Q→P).

Are there any relevance logics worth note that include Peirce’s law? Are there any obvious flaws with it as a principle of Relevance Logic?

Standefer discusses minimal requirements on relevance logics and settles on variable sharing supplemented by detachment and adjunction. He then shows that P→(Q→P) cannot be a theorem in any such logic.

@Conifold yes, but Pierce’s Law doesn’t prove P→(Q→P)  with just substitution and Modus Ponens.

Its contrapositive is pretty close to that with negated letters. I do not remember how much you need to derive that formally, but not too much.

@Conifold that would require (A-> bot) and ~A to be equivalent, or something like ~(A->B)->A would have to be valid.

In fact forall P Q : Prop, P -> (Q -> P) is provable in plain constructive logic: =(intros P Q)=> P Q : Prop |- P -> (Q -> P) =(intro HP)=> P Q : Prop, HP : P |- Q -> P =(intro HQ)=> P Q : Prop, HP : P, HQ : Q |- P =(exact HP)=> Qed.

@JulioDiEgidio right, but I don’t think too many people think Intuitionistic Logic is a relevance logic.

I said constructive, not intuitionistic...  And I find indeed interesting (I didn't know) that already constructive, which is (roughly speaking) lack of any axioms, not even anti-classical, does not satisfy relevance.

@JulioDiEgidio ok? Not everyone thinks the Principle of Explosion is constructive, but it can be shown valid in type theory too. Either way, constructivism isn’t a standard for relevance that I’m aware of.

Yes, indeed ex falso quodlibet does hold constructively (already). -- Though, classically we have "from False anything follows", while constructively we have "from a proof of False (a proof of) anything follows".

@JulioDiEgidio according to Intuitionists by fiat. You have to do some work to get 0=1 to be trivializing in PA without just assuming explosion and negation.

No, again: constructive =/= intuitionistic, and rather you might say that at play is the Curry-Howard correspondence, although this is becoming irrelevant to your question...

@JulioDiEgidio Minimal Logic is constructive, but does not validate Explosion. You’re correct that Explosion is Intuitionistically valid, but that does not mean Intuitionism is an arbitrary exemplar of constructive logics.

"Minimal Logic is constructive": no, it isn't.  And, for the last time, I said constructive, not intuitionistic, and constructive =/= intuitionistic.  (EOD.)

@JulioDiEgidio what? Minimal Logic is a proper sub-logic of Intuitionistic Logic. What are you saying?

What is with the downvotes?
